# sqoop import error from teradata to hive

Tags: sqoop

I am using below given sqoop command:

```
sqoop import 
    --libjars /usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/sqoop/lib,/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/hive/lib 
    --connect jdbc:teradata://x/DATABASE=x 
    --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager 
    --username ec 
    --password dc 
    --query "select *  from hb where yr_nbr=2017"
    --hive-table schema.table 
    --num-mappers 1 
    --hive-import  
    --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/GG
```

I'm getting this error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
    17/04/06 11:15:41 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
    17/04/06 11:15:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1491466460468_0029_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
    Error: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: /user/root/temp_111508/part-m-00000 for client 192.168.211.133 already exists
```

Comment: Edit your question. Command and error are jumbled and not properly formatted. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

From the error, I can guess that the output file is already in your target directory, may be from your previous sqoop import. There is an option in sqoop import named --delete-target-dir which will delete your target output directory and re-create them in your next sqoop import. Hope that helps.